# Calling database using sql and using call in label in C#.

Tags: c#, .net, sql, integer, label

So i have code that can call a string from database that works perfectly for my label but when i try to call an integer it doesn't work. How can i reformat the code below to work for an integer?

```
string MoneySaved = null;


        string sql = "Select Distinct(Tester) From VExecutionGlobalHistory Where Tester   = 'strUserName'";
        string connString = "myconnectionstringgoeshere";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    MoneySaved = reader[0] as string;
                    MoneySavedLabel.Text = MoneySaved;
                    //break for single row or you can continue if you have multiple     rows...
                    break;
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried MoneySaved = reader[0].ToString();?

Comment: works, thanks. could you explain whats happening?

Comment: I have never tried using "as string" so I am not sure how that is supposed to work. ToString is the method provided in .net to return a string representation of an integer or other object. Glad it works.

Comment: `as String` means that `reader[0]` must be a `String` already.  `ToString()` coerces the `Object` (which is what you really have) into a `String` through conversion, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked:

```
    string MoneySaved = null;
    string sql = "Select Distinct(Tester) From VExecutionGlobalHistory Where Tester   = 'strUserName'";
    string connString = "myconnectionstringgoeshere";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                MoneySaved = reader[0].ToString();
                MoneySavedLabel.Text = MoneySaved;
                //break for single row or you can continue if you have multiple     rows...
                break;
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You could also have done something more direct, such as `reader.GetSqlString(0);`  The difference is still whether or not you know what to expect from the column you are fetching.  If it's questionable, or unknown altogether, then `ToString()` is perhaps safest.